# How can i convert floating point variable into string?

Tags: floating-point

I'm using visualGDB to develop C program on STM32 device. I need to puts a float variable and some stuffs in string for puts on LCD. But when i use sprintf function don't work truly.

sprintf(buff, "Vadc=%f" , FloatToBytes.U_float);

Then i puts buff on 2*16 LCD but float variable don't visible.

visual studio version 2019

Comment: Tip: Consider use of `"%g" rather than "%f" to handle large and tiny numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

printing floats is not supported by the nao library by default. You need to add to your linker options:

`-u _printf_float`

Comment: Exactly, Thank for your attention.

Comment: @Reza then upvote and accept the answer. It is the way of saying "thank you" here